# Display all computers through LDAP/adLDAP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, ldap

I currently use adLDAP to authenticate users and to display active directory information with laravel, but I have yet to find a way to display all computers that are attached to active directory.

There is a function to view computer information through LDAP in PHP, but is there a way to list all computers on the network?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Just for clarification, all I need is a list of computer names, nothing else. I can get information on every computer afterwards with a separate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2018**

I ended up creating my own LDAP library to handle this better: [Adldap2](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2).

```
$ad = new Adldap();

$config = ['...'];

$ad->addProvider($config);

$provider = $ad->connect();

$computers = $provider->search()->computers()->get();

foreach ($computers as $computer) {
    $computer->getCommonName();
}
```

**Old Answer**

Found a solution. This is possible though adLDAP's folder listing functionality.

```
$folders = $this->adldap->folder()->listing(array('Computers'), adLDAP::ADLDAP_FOLDER, true);
```

This returns a giant array of all computers on active directory, including their distinguished name (dn), so we can grab which group they belong to, and what type of computer they are (with `ldap_explode_dn()`. This also grabs all servers (pretty much anything connected to the domain).

More detailed process at this link:

http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=documentation_folder_functions#listing_array_foldername_dntype_recursive_null_type_null=